# Writing a password validity check function

Tags: python

I have recently started learning Python and begun working through scenarios when I came across this one:

*Question:
A website requires the users to input username and password to register. Write a program to check the validity
of password input by users.
Following are the criteria for checking the password:
1. At least 1 letter between [a-z]
2. At least 1 number between [0-9]
1. At least 1 letter between [A-Z]
3. At least 1 character from [$#@]
4. Minimum length of transaction password: 6
5. Maximum length of transaction password: 12
Your program should accept a sequence of comma separated passwords and will check them according to the above
criteria. Passwords that match the criteria are to be printed, each separated by a comma.
Example
If the following passwords are given as input to the program:
ABd1234@1,a F1#,2w3E*,2We3345
Then, the output of the program should be:
ABd1234@1*

My approach to the problem was the following code:

'''

```
def validity_check(pword):
return \
    (any(i.islower() for i in pword)) and \
    (any(i.isnumeric() for i in pword)) and \
    (any(i.isupper() for i in pword)) and \
    (any((i == "$" or i == "#" or i == "@") for i in pword)) and \
    (6 <= len(pword) < 13)

raw_input = input("Please enter a series of passwords to check, separated by a comma: ")
raw_list = raw_input.split(",")
valid_pwords = []
for i in raw_list:
    if validity_check(i) == True:
        valid_pwords.append(i)
print(",".join(valid_pwords))
```

'''

My solution seems to work, but my question is regarding readability. Since beginning these Python problems I've become a bit obsessed with having as few lines of code as possible. Could the program be shorter? I chose to use a single function with ternary operators, does this compromise readability?

Also as I'm new to Python, any help and criticism with the program in general is very welcome!

Comment: "Readability" is something that's in the eye of the beholder - I've seen ultra-complex code smashed into one line because the team supporting said code understood it entirely. What I would have otherwise considered "unreadable" and "unmaintainable" was for them the most optimal solution.

Comment: That said, read [PEP 8's advice on breaking around binary operators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has some specific suggestions for formatting your `validity_check` function:

- Prefer implicit line continuation inside parentheses to explicit line continuations using a backslash
- Put binary operators at the beginning of a continued line.

Further, since you have a bunch of Boolean values `and`ed together, perform the cheapest ones first. Especially here, you want to reject a password with the wrong length before you go to the trouble of iterating over it multiple times to verify the other conditions.

Finally, prefer a containment check to multiple equality checks, and drop the redundant parentheses.

```
def validity_check(pword):

    return (6 <= len(pword) < 13
            and any(i.islower() for i in pword)
            and any(i.isnumeric() for i in pword)
            and any(i.isupper() for i in pword)
            and any(i in "$#@" for i in pword))
```

Anything shorter would probably do more to *obscure* what you are doing than to *describe* it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to solve this and i think it will help you,

```
import re

pattern = r'^([^a-z]*|[^A-Z]*|[^0-9]*|[^#$@]*)$'

wordlist = list(map(str,input("Please enter a series of passwords to check, separated by a comma: ").split(',')))
for i in wordlist:
    if not(re.match(pattern,i)) and (5<len(i) and len(i)<13):
       print(i)
```

**Note** : This regex pattern matches a password which does not belong to this category and within if statement it returns true to valid passwords.

Thank you !